# ERROR - EmbeddedRegistryService Failed to configure the embedded registry

Tags: cluster-computing, wso2

I want to setup the cluster for wso2esb,I have done database setup as specified in the link https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Setting+up+the+Database.

I used postgresql database,I am getting the below error stack while starting the wso2server in cluster mode with command sh wso2server.sh -Dsetup in Linux machine.

**code in registry.xml**

```
    <dbConfig name="sharedregistry">
        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2RegistryDB</dataSource>
    </dbConfig>

    <dbConfig name="wso2registry">
        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
    </dbConfig>
```

**remote instance code registry.xml**

```
 <remoteInstance url="https://localhost:9443/registry">
       <id>instanceid</id>
        <dbConfig>sharedregistry</dbConfig>
        <readOnly>false</readOnly>
        <enableCache>true</enableCache>
        <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
    <cacheId>regadmin@jdbc:postgresql://ipaddress:5432/REGISTRY_DB?autoReconnect=true</cacheId>
  </remoteInstance>
```

**configuration of datasource in master-datasource.xml**

```
        <datasource>
            <name>REGISTRY_LOCAL1</name>
            <description>The datasource used for registry-local</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://ipaddress:5432/REGISTRY_LOCAL1?autoReconnect=true</url>
                    <username>regadmin</username>
                    <password>regadmin</password>
                    <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
```

**Exception trace**

> [2015-07-23 21:06:57,601] ERROR - RegistryConfigurationProcessor An
>   error occurred during system variable replacement
>   org.wso2.carbon.CarbonException: Error in building Document at
>   org.wso2.carbon.utils.CarbonUtils.replaceSystemVariablesInXml(CarbonUtils.java:1042)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryConfigurationProcessor.populateRegistryConfig(RegistryConfigurationProcessor.java:93)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext.(RegistryContext.java:461)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext.(RegistryContext.java:442)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext.getBaseInstance(RegistryContext.java:321)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.getEmbeddedRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:627)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:563)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:117)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:70)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>   Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber:
>   1; A pseudo attribute name is expected. at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source) at
>   org.wso2.carbon.utils.CarbonUtils.replaceSystemVariablesInXml(CarbonUtils.java:1040)
>   ... 44 more [2015-07-23 21:06:57,615] ERROR - EmbeddedRegistryService
>   Failed to configure the embedded registry. Invalid data access
>   manager. [2015-07-23 21:06:57,615] ERROR -
>   RegistryCoreServiceComponent Failed to activate Registry Core bundle
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to
>   configure the embedded registry. Invalid data access manager. at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.configure(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:167)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:99)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.getEmbeddedRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:630)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:563)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:117)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:70)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

Comment: Remove or comment the remoteinstance tag in registry.xml , it will work fine. it is working for me

Comment: Check if <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> tag is repeated anywhere. There should be only one line of these.

Answer (score 0):

To start debugging it look at the stack trace and in particular look at the caused by section.

For this situation it seems you can either remove the `remoteinstance` tag in `registry.xml`. Also it is suggested that there should only be one instance of `<?xml ... ?>` in scope.

Also if you are still on this old of a product at this point it's time to look at upgrading to the latest.